# Using &times; within ajax ActionLinks

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to use the html special character &times; to show a ×.

Using the following code within my razor view

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("&times;", "LogTable", "Log", null, null, null)
```

The above however doesn't recognize the  &times; as a special character but rather as a string and it shows  &times; instead of  ×. Is there a specific way to escape it so it works as below

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        &times;
</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to escape it at all? I would have expected the `ActionLink` method to take care of HTML encoding automatically.

Comment: Would have thought the same but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) funtion:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&times;"), "LogTable", "Log", null, null, null)
```

Comment: This is **exactly** equivalent to `@Ajax.ActionLink("×", "LogTable", "Log", null, null, null)`